# VS Code V - Paste text does not work -> grey cursor with point

Tags: visual-studio-code, cursor

I have a problem with the copy and paste function in vs code.

If I copy some text in vs code, I can't paste this. Every time I wanted to paste the text, there is a grey cursor with a point in the middle.

[image]

Is there a combination of keys with that I can fix it?

Comment: What platform are you running on? Can you copy from another application and paste or copy from vscode and paste in another application?

Comment: What you see is `Selected text`, by default it shows whitespace in selected text. See if your keybindings have changed for the `Paste` key combo you use.